# How to Hide multiple folder with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hide

Hi I need some htaccess help
Here is my website directory structure

```
www.domain.com/sites/folderone/index.php
www.domain.com/sites/foldertwo/index.php
www.domain.com/sites/folderthree/index.php
```

Now what i want is hide the folderone,foldertwo and folderthree

So i made this htaccess and placed under /sites directory

```
-----------------------------
RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash if path does not contain a period or end with a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Change http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com (Optional)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]


#Rewrites http://www.domain.com/folderone to http://www.domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folderone
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folderone/$1 [L]


--------------------------------------------------
```

Now the problem with this code i am only able to hide this folderone 
I want to know what can i append unlimited directory there like folderone,foldertwo and folderthree and so on ?

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: While it can be done, perhaps a more to the point question is: why do you want to hide them? What are you trying to achieve? I have a suspicion that requirement is probably better handled with something else then `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Actually the index.php inside /sites will handle which theme it will use (Folderone,foldertwo or folderthree theme) , but i dont want to show users the theme name in the url

Comment: Is there a reason those folders can't be outside the document root?

Comment: Yes all those folders cant be outside of document root , Folders should be as my directory structure :)

Comment: One hesitates as to why that is needed... A little change now makes it a lot easier further on.

Comment: can u pls tell me the changes and how to achieve ? thanks